# Json to Xml convertion in java

Tags: java, json, xml

How to convert Json to xml

my json looks like this

### JSON

```
{
 "udtList": {
   "udt": [
   {
    "id": "1004",
    "subItem": "1",
    "Amount": "2000.0"
   },

]
```

}
}

### Expecting XML AFTER CONVERTION

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<udtList>
    <udt>
        <id>1004</id>
        <subItem>1</subItem>
        <Amount>2000.0</Amount>
    </udt>
</udtList>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
String xml = XML.toString(json);
```

Comment: XML.toString(json);  is not working in this case if i do so it encodes double quote

Comment: o/p after doing this => "{&quot;udtList&quot;:{&quot;udt&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;subItem&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;Amount&quot;:&quot;1000&quot;}]}}"